# Installing updates from hard drive

Tags: 11.10, updates

I am using Oneiric Beta 2.

Installed it yesterday. Then downloaded 350+ MB of updates and installed it.

Then when I tried to auto-mount my drives using Storage manager, I screwed up and the system will boot right up to the Ubuntu Splash screen, then turn off.

Anyways planning to reinstall Ubuntu again. But I do not want to have to download the updates again. I have a copy of all the downloaded update files with me.

Can anyone tell me how I can install the updates from the hard drive without downloading them again ??

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline

Comment: Not really, this one already has the files, he just wants to install them now.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb` will install all the .deb packages on the current directory in to your system.

Open a terminal, change the directory to where you saved your downloaded packages and use the command to install the packages that you previously saved.

If you have copied the packages to a USB pen, plug it in, open a terminal and change directory to where the USB pen was mounted (it should be a mount point under `/media`).

After you located the files you saved use the command to install the files.

Comment: sorry, could you elaborate or point me to a website???

Comment: I have them on a pendrive....

Comment: then after installing your new system navigate to your pen drive folder and type that command, all the deb files will be installed.

Comment: -1, this answer is almost useless.

Comment: Not its not @jrg, user has the `.deb` packages already, after installing the system again he can just open a terminal, `cd` to the place where the `.deb` files are and use that command to install the packages that he previously downloaded. How is that wrong?

Comment: @jrg fixed and already closed.